# Escaping escape characters passing in from my API method

Tags: c#, xml, api, asp.net-web-api

My API method which generates my xml looks like this (which is fine)

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
```

but somewhere in between my api method

```
 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, res);
```

and where I grab the response from

```
string api_response = client.UploadString(myurl, myRequest)
```

my api_response string above looks like below

```
"\"<?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"UTF-8\\\"?>
```

which causes my XDocument.Parse to fail

Edit: more details
I am getting the response by this code

```
  HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            httpRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
            httpRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            httpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            byte[] bytesToWrite = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(root.ToString());

            using (Stream st = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                st.Write(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length);
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string read = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return read;
```

The read returns well formed xml: 
it is only after I CreateResponse when the extra backslashes come in play (looking at the string clicking the magnify glass option)

When I return the response back from my api (as text on internet explorer), my actual text is like so "

**Figured it out**
replacing my with ResponseMessage

```
var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted) {
      RequestMessage = Request,
      Content = new StringContent(content)
    };
    return ResponseMessage(httpResponseMessage);
```

Comment: It's not clear where you're looknig at your string, or what you're doing with it. Does your original XML *really* have the backslashes in? It shouldn't. Are you actually looking at your strings in a debugger? Basically we need more information.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah I am looking at my strings in a debugger. added more details to the bottom

Comment: So looking at the string in the debugger is *already* adding a layer of escaping. I suggest you dump the text to a file, or the console instead. I'd be very surprised if `Request.CreateResponse` was adding anything though...

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand it adds a layer of escaping in debugger, but adding 3 backslashes is 2 too many. It is like it is escaping the escape keys

Comment: You really need to find out what's in the response. Are you able to use Wireshark or Fiddler2 to see the raw HTTP? Then you can determine whether it's a client-side issue or a server-side issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet looks like in Fiddler in TextView my response is "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n\n ... etc

Comment: Okay, so the problem is server-side. You need to tell us more about what you're doing on the server. (In particular, are you claiming the response is JSON, for example? If so, that would explain it...)

Comment: I am..I think.... but if I claim it as XML it adds additional xml markup

Comment: You should really add more detail of your server code to the question. Ideally show a small method which just creates a single-element document to return.

Comment: Oh that part I am returning from another 3rd party API, which looks fine (you can see this in the question, where I get response, and ReadToEnd())

Comment: You've missed my point - you need to isolate where the problem is. So you hard-code a string to return, to take everything else out of the picture. We still don't have any idea how you've declared your API. I suggest you delete this question, as in its current form it really can't help anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Okay changed

```
 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, res);
```

to

```
var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted) {
      RequestMessage = Request,
      Content = new StringContent(content)
    };
    return ResponseMessage(httpResponseMessage);
```